# Finding a way between two nodes in a grah (Storing the nodes passed)

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have got a graph, and I would like to find a path between two nodes (number 3 and 5). 
[image]

I read about finding paths in graph, and I tried to write DFS and BFS. Both are implemented and works well. However, I would like to get a list of each node visited directly from 3 to 5.
Both algorithms work as they supposed to so, when running bsf I will visit nodes in such order: 2,6,1,4,5.
Using dfs 2,1,4,5. 
But what I would like to do achieve is 6,5 (in first case) and 2,4,5 in second.

**In other words, I want to save only nodes that are on the way from 3 to 5 (Not all visited during dfs/bfs), as a List of nodes.**

I have been racking my brain for a long time, how to change my code to achieve it, or maybe should i change my approach? I should should store nodes in the correct path, or use different algorithm? I simply do not have idea how to do it.

**My bfs**

```
  public List<Node> bfs(Node root, Node nodeWeSearchFor)
 { Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
  List<Node> route = new ArrayList<Node>();

  if(root == null || nodeWeSearchFor == null) return route;
  //State is just an enum Visited or unvisited
  root.state = State.Visited;
   //Adds to end of queue
  queue.add(root);

  while(!queue.isEmpty())
  {
      //removes from front of queue
      Node r = queue.remove(); 


      //Visit child first before grandchild
      for(Node n: r.getConnectedNodes())
      {
          if(n.state == State.Unvisited)
          {
              queue.add(n);
              route.add(n);
              n.state = State.Visited;
              //If we found node, return
              if(n==nodeWeSearchFor){
                  return route;
              }
          }
      }
  }
return route;}
```

**My dfs:**

```
    public  List<Node> dfs(Node root, Node nodeWeSearchFor)
 {       
  List<Node> route = new ArrayList<Node>();
  //Avoid infinite loops
  if(root == null) return route;

  System.out.print(root.toString() + "\t");
  root.state = State.Visited;
  route.add(root);
  if(root == nodeWeSearchFor) return route;
  //for every child
  for(Node n: root.getConnectedNodes())
  {
      //if childs state is not visited then recurse
      if(n.state == State.Unvisited)
      {
          //recursive call for dfs (We are passing route)
          dfs(n,nodeWeSearchFor,route);
      }
  }
return route;
}

 public  List<Node> dfs(Node root, Node nodeWeSearchFor,List<Node> _route)
 {       
  List<Node> route = _route;
  //Avoid infinite loops
  if(root == null) return route;

  System.out.print(root.toString() + "\t");
  root.state = State.Visited;
  route.add(root);
  if(root == nodeWeSearchFor) return route;
  //for every child
  for(Node n: root.getConnectedNodes())
  {
      //if childs state is not visited then recurse
      if(n.state == State.Unvisited)
      {
          dfs(n,nodeWeSearchFor,route);
      }
  }
return route;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy, in DFS, when you reach the "end" (you cannot go forward), you have to "go back". So when you are going "back", you just remove that node at the "dead end" from your list of visited nodes.

In BFS, you have to create new list for each node visited, copy the already visited nodes of node that "opens him" and then add itself to that list.